# AWS Connect - Iterate through Connect User list and Delete Quick Connect if does not match existing user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-connect

I'm trying to create an iterable function using Python/Boto3 where if a user is not listed in the Connect user list they are removed from Quick Connects. I've looked at the list-queue-quick-connects API and the connect list-users API, however it seems like list-users only gives an email field, and the list-queue-quick-connects API gives just Name. I'm trying to figure out a way to setup a comparison and then execute the deletequickconnect api to delete the quick connect since Quick Connects are not automatically deleted when a user is deleted from Connect.

I can list connect users this way - aws connect list-users --instance-id --query 'UserSummaryList[*].Username' --output text

and quick connect users this way - aws connect list-queue-quick-connects --instance-id --queue-id --query 'QuickConnectSummaryList[*].Name' --output text.

Can anyone provide any assistance? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to list the quick connects with `ListQuickConnects`, setting `QuickConnectTypes` to `USER` retrieving the Id. e.g.

```
aws connect list-quick-connects --instance-id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'QuickConnectSummaryList[*].Id' --quick-connect-types 'USER' --output text
```

Then iterate through the returned `QuickConnectSummaryList` and call `DescribeQuickConnect` for each QC Id. `DescribeQuickConnect` can give you the `UserId` for the user. e.g.

```
aws connect describe-quick-connect --instance-id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'QuickConnect.QuickConnectConfig.UserConfig.UserId' --quick-connect-id yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

You can then check that against the list of ids from

```
aws connect list-users --instance-id --query 'UserSummaryList[*].Id' --output text
```

If the UserId from DescribeQuickConnect isn't in that list it can be deleted. I'm reasonably sure that deleting the QC removes it from the QCs for any queue it is attached to :)

Comment: Wow, this really helps!! Thank you so much! I had no idea you could combine the querying like that :)